# Integration server is going down throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: ibm-sterling

I have several integration servers which are running on unix box. These servers pick data from a websphere queue and process them. One of the server is automatically going down giving **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**:

> GC overhead limit exceeded.

I want to increase the `JVM` parameter for this particular server on uinx. 
How can i do that? Is there any command to do so? Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the *startIntegrationServer.sh* you can see the integration servers start with below arguments:

```
${JAVA} -classpath Foundation/jar/bootstrapper.jar ${AGENT_JAVA_OPTS} com.sterlingcommerce.woodstock.noapp.NoAppLoader -class com.yantra.integration.adapter.IntegrationAdapter -f Foundation/properties/AGENTDynamicclasspath.cfg -invokeargs "$@"
```

So you can pass `Minheap` `Maxheap` `Maxpermsixe` like below in *startIntegrationServer.sh* and start the servers:

```
${JAVA} **$MINHEAP $MAXHEAP $MAXPERMSIZE** -classpath Foundation/jar/bootstrapper.jar ${AGENT_JAVA_OPTS} com.sterlingcommerce.woodstock.noapp.NoAppLoader -class com.yantra.integration.adapter.IntegrationAdapter -f Foundation/properties/AGENTDynamicclasspath.cfg -invokeargs "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the Sandbox.cfg file to increase the memory parameter and run setupfile.cmd